# Failed to re-publish a page - Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

We are getting some strange error when re-publishing a page.
The page was published successfully the first time and we can see the page from the presentation server.

When we tried to publish it again (no changes - just a re-publish) the publish fails.
The page ran OK within template builder and we got the correct html output, it failed in the last committing deployment step (Prepare Transport, Transporting, Preparing Deployment and Deploying are all successful).

Once it fails to publish the second time, it always fails to publish, and we can't un-publish it either. Also when we make a copy of the failed page and create a new page, we can publish the new page first time, the new page then fails to publish the second time with the same error.

Here is the error msg:

```
Committing Deployment Failed
Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed,
Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4210-66560, For input string: "",
For input string: "", Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-4210-66560,
For input string: "", For input string: ""
```

Does anyone know what would cause this error?

Comment: It appears you are talking about a CMS. I doubt that you will get any answers on [SF], which focuses on system administration. The question might fit on http://webmaster.stackexchange.com, but please check their FAQ and archive first.

Comment: Hi Sven, we've been using Server Fault for Tridion CMS Server Administration tasks & questions. Tridion servers can be as complex as anything you deal with here, so it seems more appropriate than webmaster (i.e., Tridion is not Wordpress)

Comment: @NunoLinhares Server Fault is not Internet Tech Support -- the error message you're reporting is specific to Tridion, and should really be addressed to SDL/Tridion support. If your question were about installing/configuring Tridion we could offer some limited help, but this is really starting to hit the edge of what would be on-topic here. CMS systems really get their own sites (like [drupal.se], [sharepoint.se]) as they're specialist areas.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion It's getting there. I agree with you that it should be addressed to Support, but people still post here anyway

Comment: @NunoLinhares People run red lights and stop signs too :-) I'll see if the other folks posting in [tag:tridion] have already committed to that proposal. Maybe we can push you over the edge.

Comment: Thanks @voretaq7, I'll do my part on it too and try to stop people from posting questions too localized to tridion

Comment: Specifically re: your question though, you are having some kind of DB / SQL error -- If applying the latest patches like Chris Summers suggested doesn't help you should check your database logs to see what the query looks like and that may help you debug the issue. There's really not enough information here for us to tell you what's wrong other than "your database doesn't like something Tridion is handing it" :-/

Comment: From the FAQ: On-topic subjects include "Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization". We're talking here about server software, and how to diagnose configuration/infrastructure problems. I'll agree, though, that once the area51 proposal goes through, this question will be *more* on-topic there.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suggest installing the hot fix roll-up for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, there are a lot of patches for the deployer and transport services. If that does not solve the issue, please add any new errors to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a separate publisher and also the publisher on the CMS make sure any Custom Event System, Resolvers, etc are installed on both.  Also, if using the Razor Mediator, it needs to be installed on both as well. Many times random publishing issues are the cause of using multiple publishers that are configured differently.